# Date conversion error while loading into pandas dataframe from spark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, type-conversion

I am getting the below error while trying to convert a spark data frame to pandas data frame

here is the **code to fetch two columns** from a table

```
    import pyspark as py
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import *
    import pandas as pd


    spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .master("local") \
            .appName("test") \
            .getOrCreate()

    push_down_query="(SELECT FILE_DATE,count(*) CLOSE FROM STOCK_DATA_BSE group by FILE_DATE order by 1,2 asc) LUMAX ";

    stock_data = spark.read\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl")\
    .option("dbtable", push_down_query)\
    .option("user", "****")\
    .option("password", "****")\
    .load()

    sdp=stock_data.toPandas()
```

**error message goes like this**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-c6a76dcaff3f>", line 13, in <module>
    sdp=stock_data.toPandas()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 1991, in toPandas
    _check_series_convert_timestamps_local_tz(pdf[field.name], timezone)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1837, in _check_series_convert_timestamps_local_tz
    return _check_series_convert_timestamps_localize(s, None, timezone)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1823, in _check_series_convert_timestamps_localize
    lambda ts: ts.tz_localize(from_tz, ambiguous=False).tz_convert(to_tz).tz_localize(None)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2355, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1824, in <lambda>
    if ts is not pd.NaT else pd.NaT)

File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 652, in pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp.tz_convert (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:13875)

TypeError: Cannot convert tz-naive Timestamp, use tz_localize to localize
```

i am not sure how to convert the date from database format to pandas format.

has anyone faced similar scenario?

appreciate your help on this